# How do I get a list of Mailboxes that are forwarding to Contacts with a specific domain in Exchange 2007?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, email-server, exchange-2007

I need to put together a list of Mailboxes - specifically the Primary SMTP address - that are forwarding to contacts with a specific domain in the SMTP address. For example, the filter would accept a Mailbox with identity "John Doe" if the Forwarding Address points to a Contact with the primary SMTP address "jdoe@specificdomain.com".

I can get the Mailboxes that have a forwarding address set with the following command using the Exchange 2007 Shell.

```
$forwardingMailboxes = Get-Mailbox | where {$_.ForwardingAddress -ne $Null}
```

How do I filter $forwardingMailboxes further by accepting only the Mailboxes that are forwarding to Contacts with an SMTP address with a specific domain?

Answer (score 1):

This may do what you need

```
Get-Mailbox | where {$_.ForwardingAddress -ne $null} | select forwardingaddress | foreach-object { Get-MailContact $_.forwardingaddress -ErrorAction silentlycontinue } | where { $_.primarysmtpaddress -like '*forwardingdomain.com' }
```

it pulls out a list of forwarded mailboxes, filters it by those which are forwarded to contacts only, and then filters that by the primarysmtpaddress field to only select the domain you need.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for. The command returns a list of the Contacts that are being forwarded to an SMTP address with a specific domain. I need the command to return a list of the Mailboxes that are doing the forwarding. I was able to get that list by assigning the Contacts to a variable and then getting the Mailboxes that have the same contact name. It worked out in my case because the Mailbox names and Contact names are identical.

Comment: There is a solution to that as well. There exists a -passthru  switch which passes the selected value down the pipe. Alternately, and clearer to read, would be to use a multi line version and just build a return object which contains a column with the source mailbox and a second column with the dest mail address.

Comment: Agree with @IanMurphy that an actual script which pulls and tests the forwarding address, then returns the mailbox object for the ones that are forwarding to a given domain.  Use advanced function(s).  Pipeline input the domain and the array of mailboxes from get-mailbox, and output an array of mailboxes that forward to that domain.